# Microsoft Access Subform Definition Changed

Tags: ms-access, subform

I hardly dare bring up this topic because what is happening is so extremely strange - but I'll try anyway.

I have a large Access DB for a customer. One of the forms in the front end has a series of subforms. Until recently, everything was working well.

Now, when a new version of the front end is sent to the customer (I tried Team Drive as well as WeTranser) this results in one of the subforms being changed to a different form. This form is also in the database but is by no means linked to the main form in question.

I have tested this several times: The version on my PC is still working perfectly. The version that the customer sent back to me according to my request has the wrong subform in it.

We are all working on Access 2010 with an Access 2000 format MDB. The reason for this is that the Backend needs replication.

Does anybody have a clue on how or why this could be happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself after testing together with the customer.

Copied the file via USB stick this time. The copied file was OK on the destination system. Opened file pressing shift button so no programs would run. Everything was still OK. Then opened the file in the usual way. The start form realized that the paths had changed and relinked all the tables. Except for the start form, no other forms are involved in this operation. After that, the subform had changed to a different form.

Solution (rather: Workaround): Changed the name of the subform that replaced the correct subform. After that, everything went well.

The change of the subform only occurred during the relink routine. If the subform was changed to the correct one manually after relinking, it remained correct.

Reasons? Has Microsoft released updates to MS Access recently? We'll probably never know.